# how to calculate the typical reduction for the below data and also find the evidence that the mean reduction is different from 0

Tags: r, statistics

below is my data set

```
structure(list(BP = c(8L, 12L, 10L, 14L, 2L, 0L, 0L, -6L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, -3L, -4L, 2L), Diet = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("FishOil", "RegularOil"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

I have calculated the mean and p-value for the **regular oil group**. using below code

```
# mean for regular oil.
meanForRegularOilDiet <- with(ex0112,tapply(BP,Diet,mean))["RegularOil"]
meanForRegularOilDiet

#p-value
test <- t.test(ex0112$BP[ex0112$Diet=='RegularOil'])
test
#two-sided p-value
test$p.value
```

Now by Assessing the degree of evidence i.e., P-value and mean, how can I find that the mean reduction for the regular oil diet group is different from 0 and also What is the typical reduction in blood pressure expected from the regular oil diet group (for individuals like these men)? **(only for regular oil diet group)**

Comment: Hello Sreerangam welcome to SO. I think this question is more about statistics and you might get better answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com Your question is not clear: you want the reduction for the regular oil, compared to what? Is `BP` already a reduction (compared to an appropriate control)? In that case the t-test you're doing might be good (although `BP` doesn't look normally distributed, you could consider a Wilcoxon test). The mean is a "typical reduction", and the p-value tests whether this reduction is bigger than expected by random chance. Doesn't look like it's the case here

Comment: Also, if you wish to test Fish Oil, you'll have to correct for multiple comparisons (e.g. Bonferroni).